# scheme on guile: let-syntax invalid?

Tags: macros, scheme, guile

For a functional programming assignment, I am writing a scheme macro that translates scheme code to coffeescript code. I am using guile on Linux Mint 12, and have (use-syntax (ice-9 syncase)) active.

Currently, I am trying to nest let-syntax in define-syntax and I keep getting an unexpected 'invalid syntax' error. Please excuse any poor programming habits as I am a scheme newbie. :)

My code:

```
(define-syntax coffee
  (syntax-rules (define lambda)
    ; translate define function
    ((_ (define arg1 arg2)) 
     (begin
       (let-syntax ((temp
                     (syntax-rules ()
                       ((_) (quote-replace-list 'arg1 'arg2))))))
       (if (list? 'arg1) 
           (string-append (coffee (car 'arg1)) " = " 
                          (comma-splice (cdr 'arg1)) " -> " 
                          (coffee temp))
           (string-append (coffee 'arg1) " = " 
                          (coffee arg2)))))))
```

and my output:

```
guile> (load "hw2-retry.scm")
guile> (coffee (define (x y) (+ x y)))
ERROR: invalid syntax (let-syntax ((temp (syntax-rules () ((_)
(quote-replace-list (quote #) (quote #)))))))
ABORT: (misc-error)
```

After several of trying to research this error, I'm starting to think I am just not understanding something fundamental. I was sure you could nest a let-syntax inside a define-syntax. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What output were you expecting from your sample?

Comment: (coffee (define (x y) (+ x y)) should convert the define statement from scheme into equivalent coffeescript. Though, this particular example is kinda nonsensical. if I have my syntax right, the output should be: x = (y) -> x + y

Comment: let-syntax is like let in the sense that it's scoped around a body.  But your use of `let-syntax` here has no body.  You can tell this because the `(let-syntax ...)` is indented at the same level as the `(if (list? ...) ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Scheme R<sup>5</sup>RS specification](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.3.1), `let-syntax` has the following syntax:

> ```
>  (let-syntax <bindings> <body>)
> ```
>
> Syntax:  should have the form
>
> ```
> ((<keyword> <transformer spec>) ...)
> ```

The problem with `let-syntax` in your code (or at least, one of the problems) is that the `if` should be enclosed in the body portion, as dyoo mentioned. In other words, you should indent the `if`, remove a closing parenthesis from the end of line 8, and add that closing paren at the end of line 14.

Comment: Thank you--I ended up using a different approach entirely to solve my assignment, but what you and dyoo said still helped.